# How to remove focus on Button click?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, antd

I'm trying to remove the grey focus when you click a button. Does anyone know how to remove this persistent focus? Ideally I want to color to revert back to it's original after button click.

[image: Edit dark-hill-9yjpn]

Comment: Rephrase your question, make it more clear. The link you've sent shows so many buttons. 

Try to add some codes here and let us know what you've tried so far. The links may break in long run, but the code persists on this platform.

Comment: updated link. Please click on one of the button, it will be slightly lighter and the only way it reverts back to its original color is if you click away from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add this to your styles. Make the focus color the same as the original.

```
.ant-btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: #1890ff !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your styles. Make the focus and hov color the same as the original.

```
.ant-btn-primary:hover, .ant-btn-primary:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1890ff;
  border-color: #1890ff;
}
```